# showing json on console through rest

Tags: java, rest

I am developing a rest web service , which is below rite now upon execution showing  me a file to download that contain json when access through browser now i do not want that file downloadable option to be displayed I want that it should me json on browser itself so for that please advise what necessary changes I need to make in the below code in order to achieve the same

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {

    private final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserController.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    // =========================================== Get All Users ==========================================


    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<User>> getAll(@RequestParam(value = "offset", defaultValue = "0") int offset,
                                             @RequestParam(value = "count", defaultValue = "10") int count) {
        LOG.info("getting all users with offset: {}, and count: {}", offset, count);
        List<User> users = userService.getAll(offset, count);

        if (users == null || users.isEmpty()){
            LOG.info("no users found");
            return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(users, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

One that i observed is lets say if i open the same in google chrome browser json get open but in other browser it gives me file downloadable option

Answer (score 0):

It is matter of content-type header. If you set content-type to "application/json" then Firefox will show json data, not offer download option.